# How geth verify the rewards for miner in ethereum?

Tags: mining, verify

In the Finalize() function of ethash consensus, the rewards to miner and uncles are given by directly state.AddBalance().

where I can validate the rewards? I guess there are two places

1)VerifyHeader

2)VerifySeal

I am not sure where rewards are stored in one of the above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When node import batch of blocks from canonical chain then it will run block validation and one of the validations is to verify the state root. Reward/Balance was include in the state root validation.

You can find the source code in below path

.../go-ethereum/core/block_validator.go

```
func (v *BlockValidator) ValidateState(block, parent *types.Block, statedb *state.StateDB, receipts types.Receipts, usedGas uint64) error {
    header := block.Header()
    if block.GasUsed() != usedGas {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid gas used (remote: %d local: %d)", block.GasUsed(), usedGas)
    }
    // Validate the received block's bloom with the one derived from the generated receipts.
    // For valid blocks this should always validate to true.
    rbloom := types.CreateBloom(receipts)
    if rbloom != header.Bloom {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid bloom (remote: %x  local: %x)", header.Bloom, rbloom)
    }
    // Tre receipt Trie's root (R = (Tr [[H1, R1], ... [Hn, R1]]))
    receiptSha := types.DeriveSha(receipts)
    if receiptSha != header.ReceiptHash {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid receipt root hash (remote: %x local: %x)", header.ReceiptHash, receiptSha)
    }
    // Validate the state root against the received state root and throw
    // an error if they don't match.
    if root := statedb.IntermediateRoot(v.config.IsEIP158(header.Number)); header.Root != root {
        return fmt.Errorf("invalid merkle root (remote: %x local: %x)", header.Root, root)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: ValidateState check the validation of statdb, but not verify the value of reward a miner add to coinbase address.

Comment: but if any difference reward will make the state root of remote and local difference then this error will return `return fmt.Errorf("invalid merkle root (remote: %x local: %x)", header.Root, root)`

a.k.a broken the consensus rule